# My python code can't load a dll file compiled with golang

Tags: python, go, dll, build

I'm trying to make a dll file with golang and load it in my python code, but I see the below error.

python code :

```
import ctypes

hllDll = ctypes.WinDLL("./test.dll")
hllDll.Hello()
```

What I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\sangg\ColumnIntegrator\pythoncode.py", line 3, in <module>
    hllDll = ctypes.WinDLL("./test.dll")
  File "C:\Users\sangg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1은(는) 올바른 Win32 응용 프로그램이 아닙니다 (Means "[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application")
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm missing? I found some questions and answers that it's a quite common error when I make a 32bit dll file and try to run it with 64 bit python interpreter.
But when I checked with "gcc -v", "go env" and "print(platform.architecture())", it turned out :

gcc -v :

```
COLLECT_GCC=C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

go env :

```
set GO111MODULE=
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\sangg\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\sangg\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOEXPERIMENT=
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\sangg\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\sangg\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.18.3
set GCCGO=gccgo
set GOAMD64=v1
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=c:\Users\sangg\ColumnIntegrator\go.mod
set GOWORK=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\sangg\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build2882286567=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

platform.architecture (python) :

```
('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
```

I made this dll file with the below command.

```
go build -buildmode=c-archive -o test.dll test/test.go
```

Answer (score 0):

Build mode c-archive is the wrong mode to create a Windows DLL. You should use c-shared. You also need additional linker flags. This should work:

```
go build -buildmode=c-shared -ldflags="-w -s -H=windowsgui" -o test.dll test/test.go
```

Assuming your *test/test.go* also includes `import "C"`, an empty `main()` function, and `//export EXPORTED_FUNCTION_NAME` comments before each Go function you want exported.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but when I tried what you suggested, another error appeared :
`C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\sangg\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-76042113\000005.o: in function `_cgo_preinit_init':
\\_\_\runtime\cgo/gcc_libinit_windows.c:30: undefined reference to `__imp___iob_func'
...(the rest omitted)`  

Does this mean that there's something wrong with the mingw64 installed in my computer?

Comment: Sorry, but I have very little experience building things on Windows. So I'm out of ideas. Something I've seen mentioned elsewhere is that this can be due to incompatible binaries; possibly due to artifacts from your previous attempts to build your DLL. Try adding the `-a` flag to the `go build` command.